# Heroku vite issue laravel 9

Tags: heroku, vite, laravel-9

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYCmR.jpg)

vite v2.9.14 dev server running at:

> Local: http://localhost:3000/
> Network: use `--host` to expose

ready in 309ms.

Laravel v9.19.0

> APP_URL: http://localhost
> node:internal/errors:465 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 5ms
> ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
> ^

Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/app/vendor/league/commonmark/src/Extension/CommonMark/Delimiter/Processor'
at FSWatcher. (node:internal/fs/watchers:244:19)
at Object.watch (node:fs:2264:34)
at createFsWatchInstance (/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-c9998dc6.js:45537:17)
at setFsWatchListener (/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-c9998dc6.js:45584:15)
at NodeFsHandler$1._watchWithNodeFs (/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-c9998dc6.js:45739:14)
at NodeFsHandler$1._handleDir (/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-c9998dc6.js:45975:19)
at runMicrotasks ()
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async NodeFsHandler$1._addToNodeFs (/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-c9998dc6.js:46025:16)
Emitted 'error' event on FSWatcher instance at:
at FSWatcher._handleError (/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-c9998dc6.js:47233:10)
at NodeFsHandler$1._addToNodeFs (/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-c9998dc6.js:46053:18)
at runMicrotasks ()
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
errno: -28,
syscall: 'watch',
code: 'ENOSPC',
path: '/app/vendor/league/commonmark/src/Extension/CommonMark/Delimiter/Processor',
filename: '/app/vendor/league/commonmark/src/Extension/CommonMark/Delimiter/Processor'
}

Comment: Did you resolve your issue? I am running into the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73681465/heroku-laravel-vite-not-found